# Baidu Cloud Push on AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, baidu

I am using the AWS SNS for sending the Mobile Push. And using "Baidu Cloud Push" as Android push service.

We found that there are some problems appeared when we sending the push to the Android device. As the document says, we may set the message type as *"alert notification"* with *"AWS.SNS.MOBILE.BAIDU.MessageType"*. But we found that all our push is marked as an *"in-app message"* when is different as before.

Does anyone have an idea to solve it? Thank you very much